# Linked Partial View Not Found By MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

Given two projects:

```
Project.Common
> Helpers
>> _PartialView.cshtml

Project.FirstProject
> Views
>> Shared
>>> (linked) _PartialView.cshtml
```

I have added a linked reference to `_PartialView.cshtml` to `Project.FirstProject`, linked from `Project.Common`:

[image]

However, what works *when I copy the file to this location* no longer works with the linked version.

I get the classic MVC "View not found" error (I have renamed the view here in the name of brevity):

```
The partial view '_PartialView' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/_PartialView.aspx
~/Views/Home/_PartialView.ascx
~/Views/Shared/_PartialView.aspx
~/Views/Shared/_PartialView.ascx
~/Views/Home/_PartialView.cshtml
~/Views/Home/_PartialView.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/_PartialView.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/_PartialView.vbhtml
```

Why can't MVC find the linked partial view?

Comment: Because its in another project. I think partial views are only scoped to the project not the solution

Comment: @zgood I would expect linking cshtml files to behave in the same way that C# and js files behave.

Comment: Well I guess your expectations are wrong sorry